# WiFi experiences severe delay when more than one user is using the internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, lag

Recently got fibre internet, 40/2, works fine when on one PC. If two access it at once, even if one is only on Google images and not even watching 1080p streams it lags horribly (5.5k+ ping).

I don't know if it's the router doing it - called ISP, they advised changing the WiFi channel which did nothing, but I suspect it is, since it's fine with one user only, as if there is lag and I restrict all but one PC from the network, it stops. Would getting a better router improve this? I'm considering buying a different router as I doubt the ISP will be very helpful, and installing DD-WRT or something on it. Is this likely to work? I haven't had to deal with any similar problem before so I don't know.

Comment: How old is your router, and is it better for a little bit when you reboot it?

Comment: What is "5.5k+ ping"? Is that 5,500 milliseconds, so 5.5 seconds?

Comment: @piercedRichard We only got it when they put the internet so about six months ago. There's a known issue where the internet slows down after it's been on a while but this isn't it. Rebooting doesn't do anything, the second another user connects and tries to do anything, it starts going slowly. It's the HG533, if it helps.

Comment: @Spiff 5.5 seconds, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend two things:

1. Check with your ISP to see if they have a fix, or if you can get a different device that doesn't do routing (passes through to a router that you buy), as they are usually more reliable in the long term
2. Using your own router either attached to the modem (if you have a separate fiber modem) or attached to the existing router.

While there is usually a performance loss when adding a second consumer-level device (or even a business-grade device like Cisco), because you have this existing issue, and the ISP router would only see one device and interface with one device, it should fix the problem.

I generally don't go with an ISP-provided router (unless they provide a Cisco Catalyst or better), as they have generally provided the cheapest device possible. Also keep in mind that older devices tend to fail (3-4 years old, then it starts having issues = replace it soon). This happens to all consumer-level devices that I've dealt with in the last few years - If you aren't willing to spend $500+ USD, then buy a mid-grade consumer device instead that has the features you need/want.

Comment: I was in contact with the ISP about a month after it started but they weren't too helpful; suggested changing the wifi channel which did nothing. There's actually an Openreach fibre modem there already, which is plugged directly into the master socket, then the router is plugged into the modem. I figure I'll just try the ISP again to see if they'll replace it or pick up some fairly decent looking router off the internet.

Comment: Yeah - That's probably a good idea. If it's having trouble with more than one client, the issue is most likely on the router (not the modem/service, as they can't tell how many computers you have behind the router - it's all traffic to them). If it's something that you paid for (i.e. "For only $29.95, we'll install a great router that will give you the best speed"), they should at least take it back. For #1 above, I thought you had a combination device like Comcast sells/gives to their customers, so replacing the router is about the best option.

Answer (score -1):

If it's true that your router just can't balance the load between more than one user (but with only one user it works) then you can try connecting only PC1 to the router (via cable) and then start a wifi hotspot on PC1 to which you will connect PC2, PC3, ..., and so on. In that way the router will only see many requests from PC1, and PC1 itself will manage the load.

If you try this and it works good on all PCs, then buy another router.